# Laravel query builder 'where' method is broken

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Any example from http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries using ->where(...) fails for me. Generated query always has question marks instead of passed values.

Code:

```
var_dump(
    DB::table('users')
    ->where('votes', '>=', 100)
    ->toSql()
);
```

Outputs:

```
string 'select * from `users` where `votes` >= ?' (length=40)
```

Comment: It is not broken. Eloquent will replace `?` with the value `100` on the actual query.

Comment: @JakeOpena I thought ->toSql() should provide an actual query, am I wrong?

Comment: It produces the query prior to prepared variables being bound to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments of your question, nothing is broken, running `->toSql()` will show the query before any values are bound to it.

If you need to see the values that are bound to the query you can use `DB::listen()`:

```
DB::listen(function($sql, $bindings, $time) {
    var_dump($sql); // this is the query
    var_dump($bindings); // these are the values bound to the query
    var_dump($time); // time query took to process
});
```

You will find this article very useful: https://scotch.io/tutorials/debugging-queries-in-laravel